# Getting input stream using Java Mail and showing progress

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail with imap protocol to access my Gmail account and get the InputStream from a attachment BodyPart. The problem is when I start downloading the file, I want to show the download progress but the file is downloaded without showing the progress.  I tried logging out the bytes read inside the loop and I got all the log when the downloading proccess finished.

***Edit:** It seems that the InputStream Object that I get using getInputStream() is holding all the content already, meaning that the content is already downloaded to my system somewhere in the memory and when I read that data it transfers to me very quickly.*

I'm using AsyncTask for this. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
protected Void doInBackground() {
    InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

    int bytesRead;
    byte[] buf = new byte[MySettings.DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];

    while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buf)) != -1) {
        totalBytes += bytesRead;
        publishProgress((int)(((double)((double)totalBytes/(double)size))*100));
        fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    bis.close();

    mDialog.dismiss();
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    mDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mDialog = displayWorkingDialog(messageWhileDownloading, c);
}

public void displayWorkingDialog(String message, Context c) {
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    mDialog.setMessage(message);
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);

    mDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    mDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Anyone has an idea here? I'm pretty stuck.